# Robot framework: URL Get location and editing URL

Tags: robotframework

I'm new with `robotfw`.
I would like to get current URL and edit it and then reuse part of it
like this:

```
Navigate to somewhere
    ${Url} = Get location
    #when ${Url} is www.site.com/123/wrongplace
    #${Url2} = www.site.com/123/
    click link    link=${Url2}
```

Need only `www.site.com/123` part of it. But the
number part '123' changes everytime so first slash from right would be the marker to use..
How to edit it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the [Split String From Right](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String%20From%20Right) keyword.

Here is an example to help you:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  String

*** Test Case ***
mytest
    ${url} =  Set Variable  www.site.com/123/wrongplace
    ${modified_url} =  remove_chars_after_first_slash_from_right  ${url}    
    Log To Console  \n${url} changed into ${modified_url}

    ${url} =  Set Variable  www.whatever.com/63466/to_remove
    ${modified_url} =  remove_chars_after_first_slash_from_right  ${url}    
    Log To Console  \n${url} changed into ${modified_url}

*** Keywords ***
remove_chars_after_first_slash_from_right
    [Arguments]  ${string}
    ${begin}  ${end} =  Split String From Right  ${string}  /  1
    [return]  ${begin}
```

And here is the output of this test:

```
$ robot test.robot
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
mytest                                                                ..
www.site.com/123/wrongplace changed into www.site.com/123
www.whatever.com/63466/to_remove changed into www.whatever.com/63466
mytest                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for your example! made it little bit shorter:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    resource.robot
*** Test Cases ***
Upload data
    Navigate to somewhere
*** Keywords ***
Navigate to somewhere
    ${Url} =                    Get location
    ${Url_import}  ${NOuse} =   Split String From Right     ${Url}  /  1
    [Return]   ${Url_import}
    Go to                       ${Url_import}/somewhere
```